# How should I use div to effectively align content on a page?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to use div to align content on my page. Suppose I want to align a menu on the left (20% of the page) and an article on the rest of the space on the right (80% or less). I am currently creating two divisions inside a single div and floating left and right and setting widths in percentages. This method works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work. Some friends suggest that I should use tables. Should I? I think tables are just a short term solution and don't follow the actual way of coding a page. Is there any other, more efficient, way?
(Edit: Didn't add any code)

```
    <style>
    div#menu {
      width:75%;
      float: left;
    }
    div#menu ul{
      padding:0;
      }
    div#menu ul li{
      display: inline;
      }
    div#menu ul li a{
      background-color: green;
      color: black;
      padding:10px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    }
    div#menu ul li a:hover{
        background-color: orange;
     }
    div#menu ul li.icons {
      display: inline;
      }
    div#menu ul li.icons a{
      background-color: white;
      padding: 0px 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    div#social{
      float: right;
      width:20%;
      clear: none;
    }
    div#social ul{  
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    div#social ul li{
    display: inline;
    }
    </style>

    <div>

    <div id="social">
    <ul>
    <li>Connect with me: </li>  
    <li class="icons"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/some"><img       src="Images/Facebook-256.png" width="24px" height="24px"></a></li>
    <li class="icons"><a href="mailto:some@uic.edu"><img   src="Images/Google.ico" width="24px" height="24px"></a></li>

   </ul>
   </div>  
   <div id="menu">  
   <ul>  

   <li><a href="http://alathw2.people.uic.edu">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://alathw2.people.uic.edu">Interesting Things</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
```

This code worked, surprisingly.
But I want to know if there is some other efficient option. Suppose I want to align three blocks instead of two.

Comment: As I mentioned, I currently put two divisions inside a single division. Align one div right and other left and specify their widths in %.

Comment: post the same code with question

Comment: this is not helping. Please show some snippets that you have tried or put some image of your expected behavior. Please put some efforts to explain your question.

Comment: Please post the actual HTML you use - it makes what you have done much clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I added the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this. I created a simple outline.

```
  <style>

 .main{
 width:100%;
}
.left_menu{
 background:gray;
 width:20%;
float:left;
}
.right_article{
 background:tan;
 width:60%;
 float:left;
 }
.social{
background:green;
width:20%;
float:right;
}
.clearfix{
clear:both;
}

</style>


<div class="main" >
<div class="left_menu" >
    Menu
</div>
<div class="right_article">
    Article
</div>
<div class="social">
    Social
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. It works the way I want it to. Any particular reason for floating two divs left and one right? I have been using clear:both; but I don't know it's actual advantage?

Comment: its my pleasure to help you.

Comment: refer this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp. it may help you...